# altbeacon library - import as eclipse project with source so I can step thru code

Tags: android, eclipse, altbeacon

I imported the altbeacon library in eclipse but it has no source code. I'm interested in stepping thru the code via a debugger. Any ideas on how to do this? AS is not an option since our project is in eclipse only. Thanks

Comment: you need to collect the source code first.. library wont help there.